# How to debug contract in Ropsten network (using orazlize.it)?

Tags: contract-development, parity, oracles

I am developing smart contract that involves random number usage. I decided to use oraclize.it to get it according to [this example](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity/random-datasource). Documentation says that Oraclize smart contract available in Ropsten net and I running local Parity node with test accounts in Ropsten.

But it totally stuck on get it running - Parity says "contract will raise error" on deployed on and only way to run it without exception is to remove all lines referenced oraclize code.

Here is my simplest contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "./oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol";

contract GetRandom is usingOraclize {
    event newRandomNumber(bytes);

    function GetRandom() {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_Ledger);
        update();
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 _queryId, string _result, bytes _proof) oraclize_randomDS_proofVerify(_queryId, _result, _proof) {
        // if we reach this point successfully, it means that the attached authenticity proof has passed!
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;

        newRandomNumber(bytes(_result));
    }

    function update() payable {
        uint N = 7; // number of random bytes we want the datasource to return
        uint delay = 0; // number of seconds to wait before the execution takes place
        uint callbackGas = 200000; // amount of gas we want Oraclize to set for the callback function

        // this function internally generates the correct oraclize_query and returns its queryId
        bytes32 queryId = oraclize_newRandomDSQuery(delay, N, callbackGas);
    }
}
```

Because Parity cannot "import" files I just replaced "import" statement with content of latest Oraclize API (0.4) file.

And it simply does not works.

I would like to run this code in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.13+commit.fb4cb1a.js) but it unable to connect to my local node. More exact it looks like it connected but contract cannot be deployed - i always got error related to incorrect JSON-RPC response (usually it means that connection to node unsuccessful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I can get Remix works with my local Parity node. I just specified `--jsonrpc-cors="https://remix.ethereum.org"` parameter and selected "web3" provider.